# Proving linear homeomorphism between function space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X,Y$ be locally compact Hausdorff spaces and $V$ a topological $\mathbb{R}$-vector space. I want to show that the map
$$
C(X\coprod Y, V) \rightarrow C(X,V)\times C(Y,V)\\
F\mapsto(F|_X,F|_Y)
$$
is an isomorphism of topological vector space.

My attempt:

I have already shown that there exists a bijection between the two sets given and also shown that both of them are vector spaces. Now all I need is that I have to show linearity for the mapping. There is a hint that I can first proof that $(X\coprod Y)\times Z \cong(X\times Z)\coprod (Y\times Z)$ but I don't see how this is useful.

I am using the compact-open topology and would anyone give me some hints on this? Thanks!

Comment: Caveat: you want to show that the map is an homeomorphism, not an homomorphism!

Comment: isn't it the same between linear homeomorphism and isomorphism between vector spaces?

Comment: You only need to show linearity, correct? What happens if you use the definition?

Comment: @supinf I do not think that it is only a matter of linearity. OP asks for a TVS isomorphism, i.e. a linear isomorphism that is continuous and has a continuous inverse. They already handled the bijection part, so linearity+continuity+continuity of the inverse is what is left to be shown.

Comment: @JustDroppedIn I admit its unclear, but OP said "Now all I need is that I have to show linearity for the mapping."

Comment: @supinf Yes, sorry for the unclearness. I need to show that the mapping is in fact a linear homeomorphism instead of just linearity.